# Null Check operator used on a null value.//chat is available for every user

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat, stream-builder

Why in this code,** chat** is for every user i want only the user who send and who he want to send but this chat  is available for every user .
And when i add reciever add it create this error **Null Check operator used on a null value**
However I have  **reciever id**: G3BXTZzjanWd4vwg4iMBv0VvkEh1
And **sender id** is G3BXTZzjanWd4vwg4iMBv0VvkEh1

Suppose I have reciever id

```
widget.id;
```

Here is the code without reciever id can any one solve my issue using reciever id as **widget.id**

```
StreamBuilder(
stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").orderBy("Date",descending: false).snapshots(),
                  builder: (builder,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
  print(snapshot.data!.docs.length);
if(!snapshot.hasData){
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
}
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
        final message = snapshot.data!.docs[index]["message"];
        final senderId = snapshot.data!.docs[index]["senderid"];
        final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        final isMe = senderId == currentUser!.uid;
        final alignment = isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start;
        final messageTextStyle = isMe ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white) : TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
        final messageColor = isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey.shade300;
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: alignment,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: messageColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: isMe ? Radius.circular(20) : Radius.circular(0),
                  topRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                message,
                style: messageTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
                  }),
```

```
     IconButton(
                    onPressed: ()async {
                      print("ID=="+widget.id);
                      if (messagecontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").add({
                          "senderid":FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                          "recieverid":"null",
                          "Date":DateTime.now(),
                          "message":messagecontroller.text.toString(),

                        }).whenComplete(() {

                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Send message to ${widget.name}........."
                              ,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1
                          );
                        });
                        messagecontroller.clear();
                      }  
else{
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please Enter text to send message to ${widget.name}"
  ,
  backgroundColor: Colors.red
  );
                      }

                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the chat messages with (lines wrapped for readability):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("messages")
  .orderBy("Date",descending: false)
  .snapshots()
```

So that loads all messages, regardless of the ender and/or receiver.

If you only want to load messages for a specific sender/receiver pair, you'll want to use a query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("messages")
  .orderBy("Date",descending: false)
  .where("senderid", isEqualTo: "G3BXTZzjanWd4vwg4iMBv0VvkEh1")
  .where("recieverid", isEqualTo: "G3BXTZzjanWd4vwg4iMBv0VvkEh1")
  .snapshots()
```

You'll of course want to match the conditions and values to fit with your actual code.

---

Note that you have taken a rather relational data model approach here by storing the chat messages for all users in collection (like you'd do in a single table in SQL).

While this may work, there are many other possible data models. Consider reading up on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching the excellent [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) video series to learn more about your options.

Comment: Then can you explain how I design chatroom ??

Comment: First off: does the first part of my answer make sense? Does it explain why you see all chat messages, and why using a query as I've shown would address that? --- After that, the question [how to model chat rooms in firestore](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+model+chat+rooms+in+firestore) has been answered in many other places before, so I recommend checking those (after reading/watching the links included already).

Comment: I mean how i design my UI . according to your explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but the question in your post I answered was "[I] want only the user who send and who he want to send but this chat is available for every user". If that isn't clear about my answer, I'll gladly help further on that specific problem. If you have another question after that, consider posting that separately.